# Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

**Compiled successfully, but browser is getting crashed. Couldn't figure-out what is going. 1st time getting this scenario**

Issue is in (ContactCard.js) file. I have placed the working files in codeSandbox please help me with this.

[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-danilo-13vz7?file=/src/components/ContactCard.js)

Comment: getting same error and not much documentation out there! good q!

Answer (score 2):

Remove `contactCard` in App.js, you don't pass it any contact and you already use it in `contactlist`

Comment: Thank you Nicolas, I totally forgot to check app.js and was focusing list and card files. issue finally  resolved.